# Is there a way to see all incomming connections?

Tags: go-ethereum, peers

I am running `geth` and `net.listening` shows `true`, but `admin.peers` only show connections to other peers for block synchronization, is there a way to list all incoming connections, which are synchronizing blocks from this local node?